# How to override a React component's CSS using emotion CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

In the below example, how to apply `background-color:green` to the `<Test/>` component without having to edit the `<Test/>` component directly?

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css, jsx } from "@emotion/core";
import React from "react";


function Test() {
    return (
        <div
            css={css`
                height: 100px;
                width: 100px;
                background-color: aqua;
            `}
        >
            Text
        </div>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
        <Test
            css={css`
                height: 400px;
                width: 400px;
                background-color: green;
            `}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: In the background, emotion uses the `className` property. If your `Test`-component doesn't accept a `className`, emotion can't change its styles

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand what you mean? As in provide a `classname` argument inside `function Test( {classname} )`?

Comment: Yes, see Dennis' answer below for an implementation

Comment: Another pattern to adopt will be passing of props down to the child component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Test` must use `className` prop which generated by css-in-js library (emotion in this case):

```
function Test({ className }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      css={css`
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: aqua;
      `}
    >
      Text
    </div>
  );
}
```

Therefore:

```
// Will use the styling defined in `Test` component (default)
<Text/>

// Will use the defined styling and override the default when possible, 
// or add additional styling.
// i.e using background-color will override it
// using background-border will *add* a style
<Text css={...}/>

// Same as above, usually used with 3rd party css.
<Text className="someOtherCss" />
```

Comment: Does this mean that it is okay to call `Test` using `<Test/>`? Or should `classname` still be specified, e.g. `<Test className="testComponent"/>`