# Styles not applied at child component with Emotion 11 css prop in Gatsby and Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, react-props, emotion

I'am using [Emotion CSS prop](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop) to style my Gatsby / Typescript application.

I am using Gatsby 2 and Emotion 11.

In e.g. my Header component I render a `Logo` component:

```
/** @jsx jsx */
import { FC } from 'react';

import { jsx } from '@emotion/react';

import Logo from 'components/Logo';
import useSiteMetaData from 'hooks/useSiteMetadata';

import Styles from './Header.styles';
import { Props } from './Header.types';

const Header: FC<Props> = () => {
  const styles = Styles();
  const { title } = useSiteMetaData();

  return (
    <header css={styles.root}>
      <Logo siteTitle={title} css={styles.logo} />
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

But on the css prop of my child component I get a Typescript error:

> Property 'css' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> Props'.ts(2322)

I added below to `tsconfig.json` and that solves the linting error:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["@emotion/react/types/css-prop"],
  }
}
```

But somehow the styles are not applied from within my `Header.styles.ts`, so I am able to overwrite/add some styles of my child component (Logo)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have such example in [`css-prop` docs](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop).

The `P` component acts like your `Logo` component, and `ArticleText` is your `Header`

```
const P = props => (
  <p
    css={{
      margin: 0,
      fontSize: 12,
      lineHeight: '1.5',
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
      color: 'black'
    }}
    {...props} // <- props contains the `className` prop
  />
)

const ArticleText = props => (
  <P
    css={{
      fontSize: 14,
      fontFamily: 'Georgia, serif',
      color: 'darkgray'
    }}
    {...props} // <- props contains the `className` prop
  />
)
```

You mean need to pass the `className` prop, see related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455878/how-to-override-a-react-components-css-using-emotion-css).

Comment: You just edited the question with the TS error, check related docs https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#gatsby-focus-wrapper, especially regarding css prop: https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#css-prop

Comment: Do I have to do something with the className prop to get this to work? I see [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455878/how-to-override-a-react-components-css-using-emotion-css) from you here.

Comment: Yes... Add the `className` prop as mentioned in the answer and the docs